# Do blank spaces in a code affect the execution time or performance of a code?

Tags: java, time, space, execution

My question is simple ,that on running of a code there is an execution time ,so if there are blank spaces in code , I mean blank spaces not spaces in string or anything ,the execution time will be same or not or it will increase

Comment: No, they do not. The parser (in detail: the tokenzier) takes care of multiple whitespaces. The compiled code will be the same, no matter the number of blanks (unless - of course - the blanks influence the semantics, e.g. a blank in a method name will most likely result in a compilation error).

Comment: Java is compiled to byte-code (the machinecode of the Java Virtual Machine). byte-code has no whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces do not have any effect on performance. Before your code executes on the machine, a lot of processing has been done and unnecessary spaces have been stripped away.

Use whitespace wisely to make your code as readable as possible!

Comment: Thanks for this .But there is a bit of time that is used by the compiler to remove the spaces means if we use this code on a field work like in a robot or something else , the time taken matters , means the time must be equal to = execution time + compilation time and here if the compilation time increases then it not good ... Am I right ???

Comment: No, you're not.  You compile the program once, then run the compiled form thereafter.  You don't compile it every time you run it.  Compilation time is not visible at execution time.   In any case, the time taken to skip that extra space in the source code is measured in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

**No,** Whitespaces (blank space) in your code are ignored by the compiler, which just skips over them while compiling the code. This also applies to comments.

Spaces will only effect the size of your source code.

Comment: Thanks for this .But there is a bit of time that is used by the compiler to remove the spaces means if we use this code on a field work like in a robot or something else , the time taken matters , means the time must be equal to = execution time + compilation time and here if the compilation time increases then it not good ... Am I right????